# Pixel Shader Giving Black output

Tags: c#, shaders, slimdx

I am coding in C# using Windows Forms and the SlimDX API to show the effect of a pixel shader. When I am setting the pixel shader, I am getting a black output screen but if I am not using the pixel shader then I am getting my image rendered on the screen. I have the following C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using SlimDX.Direct3D9;
using SlimDX;
using SlimDX.Windows;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
  {
     // Vertex structure.
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Vertex
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public float Tu;
    public float Tv;

    public static int SizeBytes
    {
        get { return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Vertex)); }
    }

    public static VertexFormat Format
    {
        get { return VertexFormat.Position | VertexFormat.Texture1; }
    }
}


static class Program
{
    public static Device D3DDevice;         // Direct3D device.
    public static VertexBuffer Vertices;    // Vertex buffer object used to hold vertices.
    public static Texture Image;            // Texture object to hold the image loaded from a file.
    public static int time;                 // Used for rotation caculations.
    public static float angle;              // Angle of rottaion.
    public static Form1 Window =new Form1();
    public static  string filepath;
    static VertexShader vertexShader = null;
    static ConstantTable constantTable = null;
    static ImageInformation info;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        filepath = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Garden.jpg";




        info = new ImageInformation();
        info = ImageInformation.FromFile(filepath);

        PresentParameters presentParams = new PresentParameters();

        // Below are the required bare mininum, needed to initialize the D3D device.
        presentParams.BackBufferHeight = info.Height;         // BackBufferHeight, set to  the Window's height.
        presentParams.BackBufferWidth = info.Width+200;          // BackBufferWidth, set to  the Window's width.




        presentParams.Windowed =true; 
        presentParams.DeviceWindowHandle = Window.panel2 .Handle;                       // DeviceWindowHandle, set to  the Window's handle.

        // Create the device.
        D3DDevice = new Device(new Direct3D (), 0, DeviceType.Hardware, Window.Handle, CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, presentParams);

        // Create the vertex buffer and fill with the triangle vertices. (Non-indexed)
        // Remember 3 vetices for a triangle, 2 tris per quad = 6.
        Vertices = new VertexBuffer(D3DDevice, 6 * Vertex.SizeBytes, Usage.WriteOnly, VertexFormat.None, Pool.Managed);
        DataStream stream = Vertices.Lock(0, 0, LockFlags.None);
        stream.WriteRange(BuildVertexData());
        Vertices.Unlock();

        // Create the texture.

        Image = Texture.FromFile(D3DDevice,filepath );

        // Turn off culling, so we see the front and back of the triangle
        D3DDevice.SetRenderState(RenderState.CullMode, Cull.None);

        // Turn off lighting
        D3DDevice.SetRenderState(RenderState.Lighting, false);


        ShaderBytecode sbcv = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("C:\\Users\\yashwinder singh\\Desktop\\vertexShader.vs", "vs_main", "vs_1_1", ShaderFlags.None);
        constantTable = sbcv.ConstantTable;
        vertexShader = new VertexShader(D3DDevice, sbcv);


        ShaderBytecode sbc = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("C:\\Users\\yashwinder singh\\Desktop\\pixelShader.txt", "ps_main", "ps_3_0", ShaderFlags.None);
        PixelShader ps = new PixelShader(D3DDevice, sbc);

        VertexDeclaration vertexDecl = new VertexDeclaration(D3DDevice, new[] {
                            new VertexElement(0, 0, DeclarationType.Float3, DeclarationMethod.Default, DeclarationUsage.PositionTransformed, 0), 
                            new VertexElement(0, 12, DeclarationType.Float2 , DeclarationMethod.Default, DeclarationUsage.TextureCoordinate , 0), 
                            VertexElement.VertexDeclarationEnd
            });

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();

        MessagePump.Run(Window, () =>
            {
                // Clear the backbuffer to a black color.
                D3DDevice.Clear(ClearFlags.Target | ClearFlags.ZBuffer, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);

                // Begin the scene.
                D3DDevice.BeginScene();



                // Setup the world, view and projection matrices.



                //D3DDevice.VertexShader = vertexShader;
                //D3DDevice.PixelShader = ps;

                // Render the vertex buffer.
                D3DDevice.SetStreamSource(0, Vertices, 0, Vertex.SizeBytes);
                D3DDevice.VertexFormat = Vertex.Format;

                // Setup our texture. Using Textures introduces the texture stage states,
                // which govern how Textures get blended together (in the case of multiple
                // Textures) and lighting information.
                D3DDevice.SetTexture(0, Image);


                // Now drawing 2 triangles, for a quad.
                D3DDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList   , 0, 2);

                // End the scene.
                D3DDevice.EndScene();

                // Present the backbuffer contents to the screen.
                D3DDevice.Present();

            }); 
        if (Image != null)
            Image.Dispose();

        if (Vertices != null)
            Vertices.Dispose();

        if (D3DDevice != null)
            D3DDevice.Dispose();


    }
    private static Vertex[] BuildVertexData()
    {
        Vertex[] vertexData = new Vertex[6];

        vertexData[0].Position = new Vector3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        vertexData[0].Tu = 0.0f;
        vertexData[0].Tv = 0.0f;

        vertexData[1].Position = new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        vertexData[1].Tu = 0.0f;
        vertexData[1].Tv = 1.0f;

        vertexData[2].Position = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        vertexData[2].Tu = 1.0f;
        vertexData[2].Tv = 0.0f;

        vertexData[3].Position = new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        vertexData[3].Tu = 0.0f;
        vertexData[3].Tv = 1.0f;

        vertexData[4].Position = new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        vertexData[4].Tu = 1.0f;
        vertexData[4].Tv = 1.0f;

        vertexData[5].Position = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        vertexData[5].Tu = 1.0f;
        vertexData[5].Tv = 0.0f;

        return vertexData;
    }


}
}
```

And my pixel shader and vertex shader code are as following

```
 // Pixel shader input structure
 struct PS_INPUT
 {
    float4 Position   : POSITION;
    float2 Texture    : TEXCOORD0;
  };


 // Pixel shader output structure
struct PS_OUTPUT
 {
    float4 Color   : COLOR0;
 };


// Global variables
 sampler2D Tex0;


 // Name: Simple Pixel Shader
 // Type: Pixel shader
 // Desc: Fetch texture and blend with constant color
 //
 PS_OUTPUT ps_main( in PS_INPUT In )
 {
   PS_OUTPUT Out;                             //create an output pixel

    Out.Color = tex2D(Tex0, In.Texture);       //do a texture lookup

    Out.Color *= float4(0.9f, 0.8f, 0.0f, 1);   //do a simple effect

    return Out;                              //return output pixel
  }



 // Vertex shader input structure
 struct VS_INPUT
 {
    float4 Position   : POSITION;
    float2 Texture    : TEXCOORD0;
  };


  // Vertex shader output structure
  struct VS_OUTPUT
  {
      float4 Position   : POSITION;
      float2 Texture    : TEXCOORD0;
  };


  // Global variables
  float4x4 WorldViewProj;


  // Name: Simple Vertex Shader
  // Type: Vertex shader
  // Desc: Vertex transformation and texture coord pass-through
  //
    VS_OUTPUT vs_main( in VS_INPUT In )
  {
     VS_OUTPUT Out;                      //create an output vertex

     Out.Position = mul(In.Position,
                   WorldViewProj);  //apply vertex transformation
       Out.Texture  = In.Texture;          //copy original texcoords

     return Out;                         //return output vertex
   }
```

---

I have done the following Chane to my pixel shader where just i am returning a colour but still it is giving me a black output

```
// Pixel shader input structure
  struct PS_INPUT
 {
    float4 Position   : POSITION;
    float2 Texture    : TEXCOORD0;
  };


  // Pixel shader output structure
   struct PS_OUTPUT
   {
         float4 Color   : COLOR0;
     };


    // Global variables
  sampler2D Tex0;
   texture2D FirstTexture : register(t0);  

   sampler texsmp : register(s0) = sampler_state  
   {  
      Texture   = <FirstTexture>;  
       }; 

         // Name: Simple Pixel Shader
      // Type: Pixel shader
       // Desc: Fetch texture and blend with constant color
       PS_OUTPUT ps_main( in PS_INPUT In )
       {
           PS_OUTPUT Out;                             //create an output pixel
       Out.Color = float4(1,1,0,1);
       return Out;
      }
```

Can you please tell me the reason behind this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling [SetTexture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174461%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in your main program (effectively). This binds the texture to a sampler index, not a named sampler variable in shader code... you're not assigning `Tex2D` in the shader anything. So when you sample it, you get black (all-zero) and multiplying all-zero the way you do will of course still yield all-zero.

You could confirm this by simply outputting a flat color from the shader instead -- don't multiply by the sampled color -- and you should see something.

To fix this, you could use the Effect interface and call SetTexture on a compiled effect, or you could indicate that your sampler should be bound to register 0 (which is what you're setting the texture to):

```
texture2D FirstTexture : register(t0);  
sampler texsmp : register(s0) = sampler_state  
{  
    Texture   = <FirstTexture>;  
};
```

Comment: I have done the following change to my pixel shader but again it is giving me  a black out put.

Comment: is it necessary to use a vertex shader first and then the pixel shader????

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct syntax to josh's solution is using

```
texture2D FirstTexture : register(t0);  
sampler texsmp : register(s0) = sampler_state  
{  
    Texture   = <FirstTexture>;  
};
```

Using `register(0);` (without the "s") will result in a compiler error, see [register (DirectX HLSL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd607359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)